# Eclipse installation error - The system cannot find the path specified?

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded the eclipse-java-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip file and unzipped it. During unzipping, i see an error - The system cannot find the path specified. What is this and why is it happening ?

here are the details -

```
!   C:\abc\eclipse-se.zip: Cannot create eclipse\features
 \org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.intellig_1.0.3.v20130211-0152-   
 b208\META-INF\maven\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature
 \org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.intellig\pom.properties
 The system cannot find the path specified.

!   C:\abc\eclipse-se.zip: Cannot create eclipse\features 
\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.subwords_1.0.3.v20130211-0152-
b208\META-INF\maven\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature
\org.eclipse.recommenders.feature.completion.rcp.subwords\pom.properties
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Are these files even needed ? are they critical ?

**EDIT -**

I used winRAR on a windows 7 64 bit machine to unzip this file. I had seen the "filename is too big (or something like that)" error when i unzipped as is. Then, I shortened the zip file name to eclipse abc. Most of the errors vanished, but the above ones remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which unzipping tool are you using? This could happen because the path name is too long, and some tools don't work with long paths.

---

Winrar is known to be one of "those tools" that don't work with long paths. Use 7-zip instead as Adrian suggested below.

Comment: Yep, my first thought too, typical Windows problem. Use 7-Zip and extract to root if possible.

Comment: @Adrian - i will install it. But, is there any workaround for it ?

Comment: @davidblaine Don't think so, just use as short folder names as possible for Eclipse. For me D:\Programme\Eclipse\Eclipse-4.2-JEE is working. But I don't like the naming scheme for Eclipse bundles neither, because of this.

Answer (score 0):

**A simpler solution:**

When it asks a folder name where to unzip, simply delete the default and give a short one like

**c:**

Then it will unzip it under

**c:\eclipise\~....**

It will not have a long folder like "eclipse-java-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64".
I hope that this is a simpler solution.

(a debtor)<><